# More options in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a select list generated by ng-options.  My intent is to create functionality where one can view lists and their items, create new lists and so on.  It occurred to me that Instead of making a button with text "Create new list" one could select and empty option from the selection list and then the select list would turn into a form (with a directive).

I am wondering about the following:

Is it possible to add custom options to already established ng-options list?  For example:

```
<select ng-options="value as value.name for value in list --> add empty option right after this">
</select>
```

Comment: Do you not have control over the `list` object/array? If you do, is it not possible to just push an empty option to it, when it's loaded?

Comment: @Thor "Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I’m not sure about the universe!" 

How did I miss that?  Next step... creating the directive that watches for the specific options.  Any pointers on that?

Comment: Like, when the user selects an option, you want to react to that? `ng-change` (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange) should be able to call a function on the change-event.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562429/angularjs-add-multiple-hard-coded-options-to-select-box-with-ng-options. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="YourModel">
      <option value="" ng-selected="selected">an option</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</option>
      <option value="">another option</option>
    </select>
```